# Byte[] to int[] without trimming 0x00

Tags: c#, arrays, string, byte

I have a byte array containing value like this:
`byte[] data={0x04,0x00};`

I need to convert it to a string a print it as str_data=0x400

But when i convert this to string the data is printed as 40 where last 0x00 is considered as only 0.

I am new to C# and I am struggling to solve this. Please help.

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to convert it to a string?

Comment: The actual types you want are a little unclear. title says int[] the desired variable name seems to be string but contains an int... please update problem description

Comment: BitConverter.ToInt16() does that.  Or a MemoryStream to store the bytes and BinaryReader to convert.  How you format the value when you print them is separate, use the X format specifier to produce a hex string.

Comment: Initially I was trying this code to covert byte array to int array and then printing it as string `int[] intArray = new int[0];
byte[] byteArray = new byte[0];
intArray = byteArray.Select(x => (int)x).ToArray();
ApplicationLogger.WriteMsg("Print : " + intArray.ToString());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear, but I think what you want is the `X2` format specifier for bytes, which will print your bytes as two hex digits, e.g.:

```cs
byte b = 0x40;
Console.WriteLine( b.ToString( "X2" ) ); // Prints '40'
```

Convert each of your bytes into a string (with e.g. LINQ's `Select` method), then join them and add the "0x" prefix.

Comment: ...except for the very first byte, where you only seem to need x instead of x2; or get rid of the (possible) leading zero afterwards...

Comment: I got the answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I used following snippet `StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(byteArray.Length * 2);
            foreach (byte b in byteArray)
                hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);`